# Is there a method to encrypt relations in between values of a cyclic value set and generate values out of this set with pseudo RNG? (all at user PC)

Tags: algorithm-design, pseudo-random-generator, permutation, pseudo-random-permutation

Is there a pseudo RNG and function $f$ with
1.) The RNG produces a value $v_0$ out of $N$ different values (set $S$).
2.) Independent of the RNG the function $f$ generates $v_{i+1}=f(v_i)$

Requirements:
$\bullet$ $v_{i+N} = v_i$
$\bullet$ $\forall i$:  $\{v_{i+k}, 1\le k \le N\} = S$
$\bullet$ $v_{i+j} = f^j(v_i)$ so it needs $O(N)$ computations (hard to compute)

All this is computed at the users PC. He has access to all variables. Given two random values genereated by the RNG the user should not know how to compute the second out of the first (= how often $f$ need to be applied).

**Question:** Is there any cryptographic method which has such conditions?

---

**Further notes**:
(*..) ... in further text means an optional simplificaion

$\bullet$ each $v_0$ is part of the same cycle (*or part of one out of a max of 10 cycles of equal size (+/-5%))

$\bullet$ There should exit no faster way to compute $v_{i+j}$ out of $v_{i}$ except in $j$ $(\mod n)$ steps (or $N-j$ steps) (*linear speed up of less than 5 times is ok)
$\bullet$ (*The result set of function $f$ can be larger than those $N$ values (up to ~1000 times)(and with this the cycle size) but there need to exists an efficient function to prove if it is one of those $N$ values.)

$\bullet$ There need to be an efficient way to (pseudo) randomly generate values $v_0$ (*not all values in $S$ need to be generated by the RNG but at least $N^{2/3}$)
$\bullet$ (*The RNG dont need to be uniform distributed among those $N$ values (but it can). It's fine if no probability of one value is much higher than 1000 times than any of a subset containing 80% of all values.)

---

**Examples**

$\bullet$Using unknown methods:
A random cyclic permutation (with cycle size N) with function $f$ which generates the next value in that cycle and the RNG could be a random number between 1 and $N$.

$\bullet$Too easy to compute:
The discrete logarithm in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ with prime $N$ and a primitive root $g$ as generator with $f(v)=v⋅g$. The RNG would just give a random value between $1$ and $N−1$. If now the user gets two such random values he does not know how to compute one out of the other (how often multiply with $g$) even if he knows all internal variables. But it can be solved in about $O(\sqrt{N})$ steps. For small numbers that would be too fast to compute. I'm looking for something similar but with $O(N)$ (or bigger).

---

**Example use case**:
[image] _ 
[image]

[image] _ 
[image]

The green square is value $v_0$ generated by the RNG.
A-F are members of set $S$.
The relation from one value to the next is equal in each picture (modulo 9).
E.g. to get from value D to E it is always 1 square to the right and 1 below.
If now $N=80$ and $f$ delivers the next value in the cyclic permutation (with size N) the following blue square can be generated like:
with $v_{i+1} = f(v_i)$ then shift horizontal $= v_{i+1} \mod 9$ and vertically $= \operatorname{roundDown}(v_{i+1}/9)$

This can lead to multiple values at same position but values which are close in cycle also share almost equal other values. Values at the other end of the cycle still share more than half of the values. This property is not needed, equal values all the time would be better.

If now given only two random values e.g. D and G it should be as hard as possible to derive the position of G starting at D.

The grid will be 3D and about 100k x 100k x 100k tiles. Neeed about $10^{12}$ unique values. Only need to be safe for standard PC (>10.000 hour compute time, not supercomputer, grid, hardware)

Besides the 'next' function $f$ also the inverse can exists. Except just a single function also a function for each dimension can exists. If that's the case only the adjacent square gets computed. It need to be independent  of the order of function execution and there should exist no (easy) way to reduce a given value to its dimension values. Else finding the way between two random values would be too easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If evaluating $f$ uses computer time $t$, a brute force attack takes on average time $Nt/2$. To have this larger than $T=36\cdot10^6$ seconds, with $N\approx10^{12}$, we need $t>72\cdot10^{-6}$, that is some hundred thousands CPU instructions. Artificialy slowing down the implementation of $f$ in the program won't help. $f$ must be inherently slow so that it is slow for the attacker; and controllably slow so that we can tune the compromize between security and speed of the user program.

The example application suggests that $S$ is a haphazard subset of a larger set with $M\approx10^{15}$ elements. We'll take it as $[0,M)$, with $M\ge2N$.

I aim only at a reduced version of the security requirement: *Given two random values produced by the RNG, a guess of the number of steps of $f$ to go from one to the other, if made with much less than $T$ seconds of compute time, has low probability to be **exact***. Towards that:

- Choose an integer parameter $\alpha$ (a larger one will slow $f$). Find a prime $p\approx\alpha N$ with $q=(p-1)/2$ prime ($p$ is a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) and $q$ a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime)), and also $2^q\bmod p=p-1$ (and perhaps $\log_2p$ unremarkably close to a simple fraction).
- Define the function $b$ on the set $[1,p)$ as $x\mapsto b(x)=2x\bmod p$. The function $b$ is a cyclic permutation of $[1,p)$.
- Define the function $c$ on the set $[N,2N)$ that iteratively applies $b$ (at least once) until the result is in $[N,2N)$, and returns this result. The function $c$ is a cyclic permutation of $[N,2N)$. See note for implementation.
- Build a permutation $g$ of $[0,M)$ using a standard [Format-Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#Algorithms) technique. $S$ is  the set of integers $v$ in $[0,M)$ with $N\le g^{-1}(v)<2N$.
- Define the RNG as drawing $u$ uniformly at random in $[N,2N)$ and returning $g(u)$.
- Define function $f$ over the set $S$ as $f(v)=g(c(g^{-1}(v)))$. It cycles over the $N$ elements of $S$ in exactly $N$ steps.

Given random $v$, $v’$ produced by the RNG, it is possible to *estimate* how many steps of $f$ are necessary to go from $v$ to $v’$: we compute $u=g^{-1}(v)$ and $u’=g^{-1}(v’)$, then $y=u^{-1}\,u’\bmod p$, then solve for $x$ the Discrete Logarithm Problem $2^x\bmod p=y$ (this remains easy, given the order of magnitude of $N$ and $\alpha$). A reasonable guess of how many steps of $f$ are necessary to go from $v$ to $v’$ is $x\,N/p$ rounded to the nearest integer. However that estimate has low probability to be exact for moderate $alpha$ (much less than $N$), and I have some hope that markedly improving it has some sizable cost.

Note: there are time/memory trade-offs possible for evaluation of $c$ faster than the trivial:

```
uint64_t c(uint64_t x) {
  do {
    x += x;
    if (x>=p)
      x -= p;
  }
  while( x>=2*N || x<N );
return x;
}
```

and the program should use these, in order to increase $\alpha$ inasmuch as functionally tolerable, maximizing the cost of a brute force attack.

Comment: J. Doe : I fixed a $N$ into $p$. A $p$ can be found: about half of primes $p$ such that $q=(p-1)/2$ prime (such $p$ are called safe primes) are such that $2^q\bmod p=p-1$; square and you get $2^{2q}\bmod p=1$ per Fermat's little theorem. We must iterate modulo $p\gg N$ many times for one step of $f$ because otherwise $f$ is going to be too fast.

Comment: @ fgrieu: with $\mod p$ and $=p-1$ it make sense now. Before marking it as solution I will do some more thinking about the estimate and its impact in security. It would be too nice if all works that nice. There need to be some problem somewhere.

Comment: I did some testing. As expected the mean step size is about $P/N$, the smallest value $log_2( (P-N)/N)$. Not sure about the theoretical largest possible value. In tests so far it was about 10 times larger than the mean (rare case, below <5 times more common).

Comment: @ fgrieu: not all primes work. E.g. $p_1 = 2000303$. It is a safe primes but with $p_1$ not all values between $N$ and $2N$ are part of the cycle. So unless some very rare (any exists?) exceptions $2$ need to be primitive root of $p$ as well. Trivial but I forgot it during searching some safe primes.

Comment: About security: As far as I understood the permutation $g$ has no direct input in security because the true value $v$ is always known. It's just to shift values to target range. Given values $v, v'$ it is hard to compute the exact amount of steps from one to the other. However the estimate function described above is quite easy. In target app even knowing it is probably in 5% range of the total cycle length (or not) has some high benefit of knowing it. So it's not the optimal solution but the best I got so far and its also an answer to the question. ty for those ideas again.

Comment: @J. Doe: Indeed, only about half of safe primes $p$ "work". $p=2000303$ is prime, $q=(p-1)/2$ is prime, but $2^q\bmod p=1$ rather than $p-1$, and for this reason only about half of the values in a given range are reached. Yes, $g$ is immaterial to security, and the estimate is pretty good. I'm afraid that it is typically within $\pm\sqrt{N/\alpha}/2$ or something on that tune, and for this reason (contrary to what I stated) we can't raise $\alpha$ too much. I'll develop that, and an improvement using [Schnoor groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group), in an extension of the answer.

Comment: @J. Doe: Indeed, only about half of safe primes $p$ "work". $p=2000303$ is one, but $2^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$ rather than $p−1$, and for this reason only about half of the values in a given range are reached. Yes, $g$ is immaterial to security, and the estimate is too good, like within $\pm\sqrt{N/\alpha}/2$or something on that tune. Thus we can't raise $\alpha$ too much (contrary to what I stated). I plan to develop that. I can improve that using [Schnoor groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group) but then fail to plunge the $S$ that I obtain into $[0,M)$, which seems a requirement.

Comment: @ fgrieu: Didn't knew about Schnoor groups (and still don't know exactly how they compare to normal groups) but noticed during research about it that there is a problem with getting values in a certain range. But while testing I also noticed that the sum of all subgroup members is a multiple of $p$ (might be also true for non-Schnoor-Subgroups). If that factor also contains $M$ the values could be added together with $\mod M$. If initial values $v,v'$ are close together they share almost all points. If far away still about 57% (if I remember correct). (other would be duplicates). WillThinkMore

Comment: @J.Doe : My idea was to use a Schnorr group modulo a large $p$ with arbitrary generator $g$ of prime order $q≈αN$, with $α$ like 10; define $S$ as the members of the group in range $[1,p/α]$; define $f$ as iteratively multiplying by $g$ modulo $p$ until getting back in range $[1,p/α]$. We control slowness of $f$ by increasing $p$ as needed. There are close to $N$ elements in $S$, we can generate a random one, and test membership in $S$. Sadly, members of $S$ are integers larger than your $(10^5)^3$ and I find no way around that.

Comment: @ fgrieu: something like $mod (10^5)^3$ is possible as long initial values with close index share almost all 'unique' values and those far away (index +/- half cycle size) at least half of it. (instead of close index it could also another subset). It wouldn't be the optimal solution but it would work.

Comment: @J.Doe : Two problems with reducing $\bmod(10^5)^3$ : A) it is very likely that some (few) elements in the subset $[1,p/α]$ of the Schnorr group become identical after this reduction, since $\sqrt{(10^5)^3}\ll N\approx10^{12}$. B) Even if we avoid/ignore such collisions, it seems we can't efficiently go back form the reduced version to the original element of the Schnoor group (as needed to apply $f$), which as I have so far read the question is a requirement. Is it OK that we maintain an elements of $S$ in both its Schnorr group form and its reduced form in the set of $(10^5)^3$ elements ?

Comment: @ fgrieu: each element or only the current? (for only current:) After generating the initial random value the function $f$ can be applied to it to generate the next elements. The results get stored as reduced form but the current (most recent) is stored until the next value in Schnorr group gets computed out of it (with $f$). .... Storing two values for each element would be too much storage.  But storing all in reduced form and the current (or the 2 last ) as Schnoor group member would be OK. Or is the Schnorr group version needed for something else I missed?.  (An attacker can store all anyw

Comment: @J.Doe: Keeping the Schnorr group version (much larger than $M\approx10^{15}$) is needed to apply $f$, and to determine if an integer in $[0,M)$ is (a reduced form of one) in $S$. Is keeping that OK? If so, rather than reducing modulo $M$, an option is to keep the discrete log modulo $q$ (which an adversary can find anyway with access to the Schnorr group version, and about $<2\sqrt N$ multiplications modulo $p$, which is significant but feasible work), and we can plunge that in $[0,M)$ with FPE, solving the collision issue. We also can slow that, if that helps.

Comment: @ fgrieu: sry, somehow I did not notice this comment since now. The main goal is generating the same values, in same order, starting from a random initial value. Furthermore given two initial values there should be no efficient way to compute their cycle index offset unless they meet each other. There is no need to store the not reduced variant except for the most current value. Only $<2\sqrt{N}$ multiplications needed? not $<2\sqrt{q}$?

Comment: If storing the log modulo $q$ is needed the ratio runtime-computation-time divided by adversary-computation-time would shrink and this would also give direct information about the offset of two initial values which should not be the case. Btw why whould be a Schnoor group of order $q$ better than a generator of order $q$ using a safe prime $p=2\cdot q +1$?